# Simplify not evaluating completely with Square roots

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, upvalues

Here's a simple question. It's no longer high priority that I know this, but it's something that can come in handy later on.

```
Simplify[a > Sqrt[b]/c + d, a < Sqrt[b]/c + d]
```

or

```
Simplify[Sequence @@ ({a > n, a < n} /. {n ->  Sqrt[b]/c + d})]
```

or

```
n = Sqrt[b]/c + d;
Simplify[a > n, a < n]
```

all outputs:

```
Out: a > Sqrt[b]/c + d
```

while

```
Simplify[a > m, a < m]
```

outputs

```
Out: False
```

How come? This isn't an issue of not considering the negative root. The expressions are identical. As demonstrated by Simplify[a > m, a < m], replacing `m` with more complex expressions aside from having the `Sqrt` function.

In fact, if I use `Surd`, no matter the nth root, even or odd, or square root, `Simplify` will evaluate completely into False.

Why? Is this something that I can fix using Upvalues? -- Finally remember what the "overloading" feature was called.

Comment: The second part of the function here is the assumptions. *Mathematica* tries to simplify the expression based on the assumptions, which it can't, so it simply returns the original function. The proper way of formulating this is `Simplify[a > Sqrt[b]/c + d && a < Sqrt[b]/c + d]`, which returns `False`.

Comment: It works with the logical negation as an assumption: `Simplify[a > Sqrt[b]/c + d, a <= Sqrt[b]/c + d]`. Even if you specify that all variables belong to the `Reals`, there doesn't seem to be a built-in transformation to deal with the trichotomy law in this case, perhaps because `Sqrt[]` is assumed to be complex-valued (unlike `Surd[]`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The assumptions mechanism used by Simplify will not try to prove or disprove an inequality if the number of variables involved is higher than a built-in limit. To decide polynomial inequalities the assumptions mechanism uses the cylindrical algebraic decomposition algorithm, which has doubly-exponential complexity, hence the limit on the number of variables is low -- by default it is 4. Your inequality contains 5 polynomial variables, since to reduce it to a polynomial system we need to introduce a new variable v to replace Sqrt[b] and add an equation v^2==b.

The limit on the number of variables can be changed using a system option.

```
In[3]:= SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"->"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"->5];

In[4]:= Simplify[a > Sqrt[b]/c + d, a < Sqrt[b]/c + d]
Out[4]= False
```

Comment: I don't have the time or energy to actually dig in to "Cylindrical Algebraic Decomposition". But from what I gather, it "bumps up" any polynomial expression until it is at least a linear expression...

Comment: Or does it "bump" it up so the lowest polynomial degree it n - k, where k is the degree of the lowest polynomial and n is a given upper limit for the transform?

Comment: Or does n, as in $R^n$ dimensions actually means the number of variables?

Comment: I've tried DownValue-ing `Simplify`, as that is already a heavy function, thus used less often: `Simplify[Greater[a, b]] := somexpr1;`, but `Simplify` is `Protected`. Tried Upvalue to Greater: `Simplify[Greater[a, b]] ^:= somexpr2;`. `Greater` is also `Protected`.

Comment: @kozner Just `Unprotect`?