# Trying to "fix" Simplify, but cannot Up/DownValue it because it is Protected

Tags: simplifying-expressions, upvalues, downvalues

There is an irksome shortcoming for Simplify that I encountered: 
[Simplify not evaluating completely with Square roots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130290/simplify-not-evaluating-completely-with-square-roots)

-- still not entirely sure if it's because of AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables being too low (raising it is NOT an option as that would severely slow down the evaluations) or because some issue about Sqrt being complexed value.

So, I'm trying ot fix it using `Up/DownValue` but `Simplify` and `Greater`, `Less`, `GreaterEqual` and `LessEqual` are all Protected (being built-in functions).

I can just change my existing library, but that would take an amount of work and break the elegance of my automated system.

I can decompose everything using `Level[_, {0, Infinity}]`, then select those that have the `Greater`, etc heads, apply the a sort of `simplifyfalseineq` function, then put it all together with the proper heads so it's everything is the same except those self-contradicting inequalities gets `False`-d. But it's ugly and expensive.

Any other ideas?

Comment: a levelhead function can be created where x < func[a, b]/c can be decomposed to {Greater, {x, {Divide, {{func, {a, b}}, c}}}} with simple recursion. Just spitballing.

Comment: have you looked at `TransformationFunctions` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the protection by

```
Unprotect[Simplify]
```

Make any adjustments you need, and then restore the protection with

```
Protect[Simplify]
```

Comment: Well, that made me look stupid. That's not on the `Protected` help page.

Comment: Just be careful about getting into the habit of `Unprotect`ing built-ins, as that can have very hard-to-predict consequences for the internal workings of MMA. Often you are better off using `TagSet` or `TagSetDelayed`. E.g. if I want addition to be the same as multiplication for symbols of the form `x[_]` I don't unprotect `Plus`; instead I do `x /: x[a_] + x[b_] := x[a]*x[b]`. This associates the rule with `x`, not with `Plus`.