# Simplify square roots with five or more variables, assumptions not working

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Mathematica 12.0 gives me a result of the form

```
Sqrt[a b + x y z] Sqrt[-(1/(- a b - x y z))]
```

which obviously should simplify to 1. However, even with the assumption

```
Simplify[Sqrt[a b + x y z] Sqrt[-(1/(- a b - x y z))], a b + x y z > 0]
```

Mathematica refuses to further simplify this expression. If I set any of the five variables to one by hand (i.e. delete, for instance, all occurrences of a) then it correctly simplifies.

What is the reason for this strange behaviour and how can I get Mathematica to fully simplify square root expressions like this?

Comment: As a workaround, I can square the result and then take the square root, but I would still prefer to understand the cause of the issue.

Comment: Try this: `FullSimplify[Sqrt[a b + x y z] Sqrt[-(1/(-a b - x y z))], Element[{a, b, x, y, z}, PositiveReals]]`

Comment: Since it chokes on too many variables, as a workaround reduce the number of variables. `expr = Sqrt[a b + x y z] Sqrt[-(1/(-a b - x y z))]; expr /. x y z :> t // Simplify[#, a b + t > 0] &`

Comment: `Sqrt[a b + x y z] Sqrt[-(1/(-a b - x y z)) // Simplify] // PowerExpand`

Comment: A problem seems to be with simplifying `Sign`. The expression `Assuming[a b + x y z > 0, Sqrt[a b + x y z] Sqrt[-(1/(-a b - x y z)) // Simplify] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // FullSimplify]` with v12.1.1 evaluates to `1/Sign[a b + x y z]` and the `Sign` is obviously `1`

Comment: @Bill, thank you. PowerExpand seems the right way to deal with this.

Comment: @Bob, thank you as well. It seems like simplifying Sign only works for four or less nonlinear variables by default. Seems to be the same problem and solution as in the related question/asnwer here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130290/simplify-not-evaluating-completely-with-square-roots?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The simplify work for `Sqrt` if we assumption that all the variables is positive  real numbers.

```
Simplify[Sqrt[a b + x y z] Sqrt[-(1/(-a b - x y z))], 
 Assumptions -> AllTrue[{a, b, x, y, z}, Element[#, PositiveReals] &]]
```

Comment: But the expression should evaluate to 1 also for negative reals or even complex a, b, x, y, z, as long as (a b + x y z) is a positive real? Why is it not sufficient to give this information as an assumption? And why is it sufficient for, say, (a b + x y)?

Comment: @André  `Sqrt[z]` is a complex  and difficult function that I could not understand completely :)

Comment: @André except when they're all exactly zero of course, in which case it's `Indeterminate`

Comment: Considering that Sqrt is a two valued function, you may understand that the simplification is not so simple.Therefore x is not equal to Sqrt[x^2.]

Comment: @flinty a b + x y z > 0 excludes the possibility of all of them being zero.

Comment: @DanielHuber if the discriminant is a positive real number, of course it is. But zes, Mathematica does not to be able to handle this assumption for more than four variables, and one needs to use PowerExpand or variable reduction as in the comments by Bill Watts and Bob Hanlon above.